# How to prove $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)^2}{x^{5/2}}$ is divergent

Tags: improper-integrals

The original problem is to test the convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)^2}{x^{5/2}}$. It is easy to prove that $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)^2}{x^{5/2}}$ is convergent, but I have checked in https://www.integral-calculator.com that $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)^2}{x^{5/2}}$ is not. How could I prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check again. Alpha tells me the integral converges.

Comment: @BarryCipra Here says it doesn't. I will trust WolframAlpha though. https://www.integral-calculator.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$, you know that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}=1$. So, near $0$ your function behaves as $\frac1{x^{1/2}}$ and therefore it converges.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [it does converge](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x%5E(-5%2F2)*(sin+x)%5E2+from+0+to+1). (I'm not sure where you went wrong in using WA.) For a proof, note the integrand approximates $x^{-1/2}$ at small $x$, with antiderivative $\approx 2\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: Well, I actually checked in https://www.integral-calculator.com and it says it diverges.

Comment: @Andarrkor I just tried that site; it gets the same exact finite expression as WA did.

Comment: @Andarrkor, Huh! It looks like you've found a flaw in that site. I would recommend editing your comment into your question. Why did you say there that you checked Alpha?

Comment: @J.G., I checked it too, and it told me the integral diverges!

Comment: @BarryCipra Because the OP said they'd checked in WA that the integral doesn't converge. However, both sites agree (for me) that it does. If you're getting the provably wrong "it diverges" result from one or both sites, I'll leave you to report that as a bug, but on my end both resources work fine.

Comment: @BarryCipra Because I didn't remember the website and thought that WA would get the same result. My bad.

Comment: @BarryCipra I have edited the post.

Comment: @J.G., curiouser and curiouser... Why would the exact same site on the exact same integral give two completely different answers? What value does it give you, anyway?

Comment: @BarryCipra $\frac{8\sqrt{\pi}C(2/\sqrt{\pi})-1-4\sin 2+\cos 2}{3}\approx 1.87607$, with $C(x):=\int_0^x\cos t^2dt$. It's possible one or both sites were misused in a way that resulted in incorrect limits being used. it took me a few seconds to work out how to set limits $0,\,1$ in integral-calculator.

Comment: @J.G., it's weird, the IntegralCalculator site gives me the antiderivative with the constant term and a $2\sin x(\sin x+4x\cos x)/(3x^{3/2})$, but below that it says, in red lettering, that the definite integral from $0$ to $1$ is divergent, as if it's incapable of evaluating $\lim_{x\to0}2\sin x(\sin x+4x\cos x)/(3x^{3/2})=0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra There must be something we're missing. Maybe the bug is on mobile or something. (I used a laptop to do this.)